# Retrieving Event Information without Access Token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating an event system for my school. We often put our events on Facebook. So in my event system, I've created an option, to just enter the Facebook ID of the event, and the system will get the description, cover image and such from Facebook.

Then I want to run a cronjob, so it will be synced with the Facebook event.

Thing is, I cannot access the Facebook Event Information, without an access token. The event is **public**, so it would make sense if I could just pick up the information. However, I cannot. When I clear my access token, it's telling me that I need an access token to view the information.

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 104
  }
}
```

So I'm wondering, is there a way to achieve this? So that I can run a cron job? The site has a Facebook app, so if I could auth through that It could work as well. In the end, It comes down to the script being able to do this automaically.

Any ideas?

Event: https://www.facebook.com/events/508611712542094

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Events's privacy is set to "OPEN", then you can get the info of the Event if you have any valid Access Token. This is described here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event

You could set up an simple app and generate an App Access Token for your Use Case. If you did that, you can request the Event info like this

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{YOUR_EVENT_ID}?access_token={YOUR_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN}
```